# Problem Checking Existence of Element of C# List using Contains()

Tags: c#

```
List<int[]> three_number_sums = new List<int[]>();

int[] _3Ints_arr = { 2, 6, 9 };

three_number_sums.Add(_3Ints_arr); // storing array in List as 2,6,9

_3Ints_arr[0] = 1;
_3Ints_arr[1] = 10;
_3Ints_arr[2] = 100;  // array now is 1,10,100

if(!three_number_sums.Contains(_3Ints_arr))  // does not exist
    three_number_sums.Add(_3Ints_arr);
```

I wonder why my program under the `if` statement still treats as exists even after overriding `_3Ints_arr` with 1,10,100?

This same concept works (`if` treated as not exists) for List of strings however once "apple" is overridden by "orange" in the string:

```
List <string> words = new List <string> ();

string word = "apple";

words.Add(word);  // storing word in List as "apple"

word = "orange";  // string now is "orange"

if (!words.Contains(word))  // does not exist 
   words.Add(word);
```

Comment: `word = "orange";` creates a new string. It does not modify the one that is already referenced inside `words`

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, the list contains the reference to the array `_3Ints_arr`.
When you change the content of this array, the reference to the array doesn't change and `three_number_sums.Contains(_3Ints_arr)` returns `true`.

In the second example you are using `string`, which is immutable: when you assign a new value to `word`, `word` is no more the reference you had added to the list.
So `words.Contains(word)` is `false`.